# How do i create and use variables in django

Tags: javascript, django, variables

New to Django and its templates.

I'm trying to set a variable given a specific situation, and that part I think ill be able to do, the code below isn't the exact conditions its just there as a demo. The part im stuck on is how do i create a variable name, and then use that name variable elsewhere. Such as within a div or within a method or anywhere else within the html file, and withing different `<Script>` tags to run methods and for really any purpose.

demo scenario :

```
{% for row in table.rows %}
    {% if row == 2 %} 
       {% var name = row.name %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 

{% if name %} 
   <div>{{name}}</div>
{% endif %}
```

my actual code Im trying to implement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   
    function map_init_basic(map, options) {
      var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true });
      {% for row in table.rows %}
        
        var x = "{{ row.cells.x }}"
        var y = {{ row.cells.y }}
        
        var m = L.marker([y, x])
        m.bindPopup("{{row.cells.first_name}} {{row.cells.last_name}} <br>{{row.cells.chgd_add}}");
        m.on("click" , ()=>{
          //console.log(`${first_name} ${last_name}`)
          {% var first_name = {{row.cells.first_name}} %}
         
        })
       
         //changed row.cells.chgd_add to row.cells.Chgd_add to make sure its matching the table
        markerClusters.addLayer(m);
      {% endfor %}
      markerClusters.addTo(map);
    }

    {% if first_name %}
      console.log("{{first_name}}"); 
    {% endif %}

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django templates are intended to render html but you are trying to render javascript. It can work but the way you are trying to do it is not a good practice; very soon you won't be able to maintain your code.

If you want to pass data directly from python/django to javascript, an accceptable way to do so is to put the data in a dictionary, translate it to a json string and have it set to a var in your javascript.

in a view:

```
data = dumps(some_dictionary) 
return render(request, 'main/template.html', {'data': data})
```

in the template:

```
<script> 
    var data = JSON.parse("{{data|escapejs}}");
</script>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

Alternative: You can use django to generate a widget with data attributes and have a javascript operating on this widget and do whaterever needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was going about it the wrong way. I'm thinking of defining the variable in my views, then assigning the variable a value in my template based on if a marker is clicked, and then using the value once it has been assigned in later down the Html file. I'm not sure if that will work or if it's something that I should do.